# Finding Total of all Values in a Column [RNG]

Tags: java, random, addition

I am working on a program that prints out a table filled with randomly-generated integers. Most of the logic is relatively straightforward and works pretty well. One thing I would like to do is to add up and print out total values for each column, as well as the final total of all the values in the table. I have searched around trying to find an answer but have had no luck with figuring it out.

```
rowNbr = 7; // ROW CONTROLS
colNbr = 5; //COLUMN CONTROLS

rpt01 = String.format("%0" + (colNbr-1) + "d", 0).replace("0",dash); //Redefine rpt01
colBld = String.format("|---------------|%s\n",rpt01); //Redefine colBld

String cnrTxt = "First Quarter";

System.out.printf(colBld);
System.out.printf("|%-15s",cnrTxt);

for(int i = 1; i < colNbr; i = i++){ //Open for loop (columns)

String regTxt = "Region " + i++;

System.out.printf("|%-10s",regTxt);

} //End for

System.out.printf("|\n");

//Initialize array

int sales[] = new int[100];
  int idx = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= rowNbr-3; i++){

String prodTxt = "Product " + i;

System.out.printf(colBld);
System.out.printf("|%-15s|",prodTxt);


for(int j = 0; j < colNbr-1; j++){ //Open for loop (columns 2)

    sales[idx] = (int)(Math.random() * 16 + 1);
    System.out.printf("%-10d|",sales[idx]);
    idx++;
} //End for

System.out.printf("\n");

} //End for

int totalNbr = 0; //Placeholder zero
int regNbr = 0; //Placeholder zero

String totalTxt = "Final Total: ";
String regTxt = "Region Totals";

System.out.printf(colBld);
System.out.printf("|%-15s|%-10s|\n",regTxt,regNbr); 
System.out.printf(colBld);
System.out.printf("|%s%s\n",totalTxt,totalNbr); 
System.out.printf(colBld);
```

Here is what the code currently looks like once run:

```
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|First Quarter  |Region 1  |Region 2  |Region 3  |Region 4  |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Product 1      |2         |10        |3         |1         |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Product 2      |15        |15        |7         |16        |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Product 3      |15        |13        |7         |9         |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Product 4      |4         |14        |11        |11        |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Region Totals  |0         |
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|Final total: 0
|---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Honestly have no idea where to even begin with this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already sequentially filled the **sales** array with random Integer values to represent sequentially displayed Regions it is then a simple matter of stepping through the array elements in increments of the number of regions and summing the elements detected in each step.

To determine the actual number of **Regions** that will be displayed and the number of **Region Totals** to keep track of, we can base it from the value contained within the **colNbr** variable less 1 (5 - 1 = 4 regions will be displayed).

Knowing this we declare yet another integer Array named **regionTotals** and give it a length of 4:

`int[] regionTotals = new int[colNbr-1];`

Now it's a matter of stepping through the **sales** array elements and summing the proper **sales** array element to the proper **regionTotal** element, like this:

```
int regionCols = colNbr-1;
int[] regionTotals = new int[regionCols];
int stepCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
    stepCounter++;
    if (stepCounter > regionCols) { stepCounter = 1; }
    int regionIndex = (stepCounter - 1);
    regionTotals[regionIndex]+= sales[i];
}
System.out.println("\nRegion Totals: " + Arrays.toString(regionTotals) + "\n");
```

Place the above code ***directly above*** the declaration & initialization of the **totalNbr** integer variable:

```
int totalNbr = 0; //Placeholder zero
```

How you format the **regionTotals** array elements into your table is up to you but do remember, the Array is zero based so the element at index 0 of the array contains the summation for Region 1.